# Angular $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I am using the following pattern for my `REST API`, but `vm.listing` in my controller is always `undefined`? Probably my pattern is not right? Is there a different pattern to use here? I don't want to call the `.get(..)` in my controller code.

```
    .factory("listingsResource", ["$resource", "$q", 'appSettings',
        function ($resource, $q, appSettings) {

            return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "api/Listings/:id")

        }]);
```

---

```
    .factory("editService",
              var _listing; 
              var _getListing = function (listingId) {

                _listing = listingsResource.get({
                    id: listingId
                });
              }   

      return {
        listing: _listing,
        getListing: _getListing
    };
```

**Controller Code:**

```
 createService.getListing(listingId);
 vm.listing = createService.listing;
```

Comment: Well `getListing` is an async call - so the data isn't there yet..

Comment: It is asyncronous, with resource you could do `vm.listing = createService.getListing(listingId)` as it supports auto expansion of promise (but you cannot access the values right away in the controller, however binding it directly to the view will work) or chain it through and assign value. Also you have syntax error in editService definision

Comment: @tymeJV but it is never there? Shouldnt when the call returns, data be available in _listing outside the controller ? In service I can see _listing populated, but in controller code (even after the call is returned) createService.listing returns undefined

Comment: @PSL Would it be better if I didnt have that intermediate service? Is it true that this resource is only making one call to the server? so If from another controller I do another get() , it will return cached data?

Comment: The reason createService.listing returns undefined is because the order of execution in your example goes:
`listing: _listing, //listing is first set to undefined in editService` and then
`createService.getListing(listingId); // _listing is now populated with a promise, but not listing!` and then
`vm.listing = createService.listing; // vm.listing is set to undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call listingsResource.get() it returns a promise. Not the data response.

You have to pass the get() a success callback and then set the listing variable inside this callback. I would do something like this:

```
    .service("listingsService", ["$resource", "$q", 'appSettings',
        function ($resource, $q, appSettings) {
            var _this = this;

            _this.listing = {};

            var listingResource = $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "api/Listings/:id");

            this.getListing = function(listingId){
                listingResource.get({id: listingId}, 
                    function (data) {
                        // Success callback
                        // Set listing keys-value pairs
                        // do not do: _this.listing = data
                        _this.listing.id = data.id;
                        _this.listing.title = data.title;
                    },
                    function(err) {
                        // error callback
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    ])
```

This works fine with a factory aswell if you prefer. Then in the controller:

```
 listingService.getListing(listingId);
 vm.listing = listingService.listing;
```